# Permission set Assign issue for SalesforcePlatform license

Tags: apex, permissions, permission-sets, sharing-sets

I have create a user with the user license as "SalesforcePlatform", here i create some custom permission sets to assign for that user. The Permission set having the **System permission** access as "Insert System Field Values for Chatter Feeds". If i assign the permission set to the new user it throws the error like as "**Can't save permission set ChatterPermissions, which is assigned to a user with user license Salesforce Platform. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Insert System Field Values for Chatter Feeds** ". Is there any other possibilities to add the Permission sets to the user with same access?

[image: SystemPermissions]

Thanks
VenkatSforce

Answer (score 0):

Force.com License Type consist of the following licenses:

1. Salesforce Platform
2. Force.com - One App
3. Force.com App Subscription
4. Employee Community User

And "Force.com license" should have access to the following functionality in Salesforce

1. Security
2. Mobile Features
3. Chatter Feeds, Updates, Profiles, Groups, Files
4. Activities, Accounts & Contacts, Reports & Dashboards. etc.

Now, we are dealing with "Salesforce Platform" License.

Based on Salesforce documentation this license type is not entitled to "Some User Permissions" and some standard features. So, this could possibly be restriction from Salesforce Platform.

Here is the link for the documentation
[Salesforce User License Type Link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_available.htm&language=en_US)